# I am trying to make a pagination with js which doesn't appear when i open my browser,, whats can i edit in my code?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make pagination with js which doesn't appear when I open my browser, whats can I edit in my code?

I only need the pagination to appear then I will continue writing my code

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <div id="slide-number" class="slide-number">slider #6</div>
    <img src="imgs/01.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="imgs/02.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="imgs/03.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="imgs/04.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="imgs/05.jpeg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="slider-controls">
    <span id="prev" class="prev">Previous</span>
    <span id="indicators" class="indicators">
    </span>
    <span id="next" class="next">Next</span>
</div>
```

**js code**

```
var sliderImages = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slider-container img'));
var slidesCount = sliderImages.length;
var currentSlide = 1;
var slideNumberElement = document.getElementById('slide-number');
var nextButton = document.getElementById('next');
var prevButton = document.getElementById('prev');
nextButton.onclick = nextSlide;
prevButton.onclick = prevSlide;
var paginationElement = document.createElement('ul');
paginationElement.setAttribute('id', 'pagination-ul');
for (i = 1; i <= slidesCount; i++) {
    var paginationItem = document.createElement('li');
    paginationItem.setAttribute('data-index', i);
    paginationItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
    paginationElement.appendChild(paginationItem);
}
document.getElementById('indicators').appendChild(paginationElement);
```

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is are facing. Waht do you need help with?

Comment: the pagination in js does not appear

Comment: @YasserEhab do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: It might because your `nextSlide` and `prevSlide` functions don't seem to exist yet. So your JS is throwing an error at that point before it reaches your pagination code.

Comment: Your code is totally not working: https://jsfiddle.net/3zb2weu7/

Comment: TommyBs... yes thank you you solve the problem

Comment: thank you all it is working now... the problem was in the empty functions nextSlide and prevSlide